# Problem with java on Windows

Tags: java

I had installed jdk-6u18-windows-i586 on my machine. Later on I uninstalled it and installed jdk 1.5.0_13 instead.

Now when I do javac -version I get

```
jdk 1.5.0_13
```

But when I do java -version I get

```
java version "1.6.0_19"
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: what is under `c:\program files\Java` ?

Comment: Your question is better suited for superuser.com

Comment: @Bozho jdk1.5.0_13 and lots of jre installations

Comment: one of which is, I guess, 1.6.0_19

Comment: No I have jre1.5.0_12 , 0_13, 0_15, jre6

Comment: well, I guess it's `jre6`

Comment: @Jack: Yes, jre6 is probably update 19.

Comment: You can change the JRE that is launched by `%SystemRoot%\system32\java.exe` using the Java control panel applet.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Super User. Your question has been migrated here, where it is more adapted. To regain ownership over your question, you should create an account here, and associate it with your Stack Overflow account in user options.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the java s/w in the registers by going the "regedit" from the run command.
Later u install the jdk 1.5.0_13 of java it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple JREs and JDKs can be installed on one machine. You are having JDK 1.5, but you have JRE 1.6.0_19.

And the version that is called from command line depends on the environment variables. Go and check your environment variables. check `PATH`, `JAVA_HOME`, `JRE_HOME`.

Comment: My JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_13...I dont have a JRE_HOME environment variable

Comment: @Jack - check `PATH`

Answer (score 1):

As the others have suggested, it looks like you have the 1.6 Java runtime hanging around.

Check your PATH and you should see the JRE location.

Assuming you don't need it any more, go to Control Panel | Add or Remove Programs and delete the unwanted JRE (which will have the Java icon and J2?? Runtime Enviroinment in its name).

Answer (score 1):

Which Java is called when you do `java -version` is controlled exclusively by the `PATH`; the first `java.exe` that can be reached from the `PATH` will be.

Other than trying to do a more clean "uninstall," what you can do is modify your `PATH` (in `System|Properties`...) to point first to the Java that you want called.